# Node.js with Express Image not uploading

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on Node.js with express and I am trying to upload image

```
if(req.files.awatar.size > 0) {
        var tmp_path = req.files.awatar.path;
        var upload_path = USER_IMAGES+req.files.awatar.name;

        fs.readFile(tmp_path, function(err, data) {

            fs.writeFile(upload_path, data, function(err){
                if(!err) awatar = req.files.awatar.name;
            });

            fs.unlink(tmp_path, function(){
                if(err) throw err;
            })

        } );
    }
```

but image not uploading and I am getting message on console

```
.write(string, encoding, offset, length) is deprecated. Use write(string, offset, length, encoding) instead.
```

Comment: What version of node and express?

Comment: express: 3.3.4 and node: v0.11.6-pre

Comment: It seems `node-formidable` (which express relies on for it's file uploads) is/was incompatible with node 0.11. It's fixed here: https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/pull/236